# Kodaira dimension under specialization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If a smooth projective variety specializes to another smooth projective variety are there non-trivial restrictions on their Kodaira dimensions?

The only interesting case I know is K3 surfaces becoming unirational.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$, the Kodaira dimension is invariant under deformation — this follows from the invariance of plurigenera, proved by Siu.

Comment: Then the focus is on mixed characteristic and equal positive characteristic.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Plurigenera are upper semicontinuous, so Kodaira dimensions can only “jump up.”  Even the unirational K3 surfaces have Kodaira dimension zero (not negative).